# Vimtutor in Neovim

Tags: neovim, learning-resources

Is it possible to run vimtutor in Neovim?

I'm learning Vim, but I installed Neovim and would like to run `vimtutor` in Neovim.

Answer (score 1):

For Neovim you can use the Neovim command:

```
:Tutor
```

Comment: Is the solution addressing your need? If so, I encourage to accept it using the v green button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)